# What is ConversationID within the _SMSMessageTracking Data View?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms, data-views

I'm just looking for more clarification on the ConversationID field within the _SMSMessageTracking data view. I believe the field serves my purpose (i'm looking to tie an inbound text to an outbound text), but I just wanted to double check since I'm not able to do a POC...

Would anyone be able to explain a bit more of some of the use cases for using the ConversationID field and/or show an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no bullet proof way to manage state with SMS as the protocol doesn't allow arbitrary data to be bundled with messages, as it can with email and the headers, dynamic subject lines or dynamic reply email addresses used there.

For SMS, Marketing Cloud uses [Next Keywords](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_use_next_keyword.htm&type=5) defined by you for an outbound (MT) send to attempt to maintain a sort of state and support "conversations". By selecting a Next Keyword, you're electing which [Text Response](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_text_response.htm&type=5) message you'd like to handle any inbound "reply" from the mobile phone numbers sent the Outbound message where no Keyword is explicitly set in the body of the MO (eg: "STOP"). The routing of the Inbound MO message is pretty crude. There's an assumption that if the SMS received is coming from a mobile number that has been sent an MT "recently" that has an associated Next Keyword defined, route the MO message to be handled by the Next Keyword of the most recently sent MT that qualifies. "Recently" defaults to two hours, but can be configured by Support request. This means that, by default, when sending an outbound message using a Next Keyword, the Next Keyword will handle any inbound messages received within the next two hours from phone numbers sent the outbound message. After the two hours elapses, those inbound messages will either encounter an error or be handled by your Default Keyword (if enabled).

An example of the type of use case supported by Next Keyword conversations might be managing an appointment for installation of a new broadband connection:

```
MT: Hi, one of our Engineers is due to visit between 5am and 11pm on 1st September. Does anyone have COVID-19?
MO: No
MT: That's great. Will an adult over the age of 18 be present for the installation?
MO: Yes
(...)
```

Each MO is handled by the Next Keyword defined by the preceeding MT

Throughout the chain of MTs and MOs between your consumer's mobile number and your Next Keywords, MobileConnect maintains a ConversationID allowing you to identify this contiguous set of communications (the "conversation"). This identifier is what you see in your _SMSMessageTracking data view and in your Message Detail reports.

Outside of the configuration of Next Keywords for your Outbound messages in the MobileConnect UI, there are a few AMPScript functions that allow you to programatically control Next Keyword behaviour. [CreateSmsConversation()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/CreateSmsConversation.htm) allows you to initiate a new conversation in your MT and set the Next Keyword to handle responses. [EndSmsConversation()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/EndSmsConversation.htm) allows you to explicitly end the current conversation with a mobile phone number and [SetSmsConversationNextKeyword()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/setsmsconversationnextkeyword.htm) allows you to set the Next Keyword in an existing conversation.